# How to pass a map<String,List> object to jquery?

Tags: jquery, jsp

Currently I am trying to select multiple options from a select tag and save it to database and i am succeeded to do it.

Now I want to retrieve this data and set it in jsp page. For that I am retrieving the data from database and creating a list. finally i am setting this list into a map.

For example: I am getting minutesList,hoursList, weeksList from database and setting them as follows

```
     scheduleMap.put("minutes", minutesList);
     scheduleMap.put("hours", hoursList);
     scheduleMap.put("weeks", weeksList);
```

Now i need to retrieve this map in my jsp and set the corresponding values in jsp. please suggest me to accomplish this task.

Comment: are u using multiselect box

Comment: how you can select multiple values

Comment: using "mulitple" attribute of select tag

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more information as to what you want to achieve.

If you want to access the scheduleMap in JSP then you need to set that as a request attribute in your servlet or controller. If you have written the whole code in JSP then the scheduleMap variable is already available to you.

Now you want to access that in jquery so the best option is that you convert this into JSON format and then use it.

Also depending upon what/how you doing you could have made an AJAX call also to retrieve the scheduleMap.

Comment: Thanks... Currently i am setting this map in a model object(bean object) and trying to retrieve it in jquery. But i failed to retrieve. Is there any method in Jquery which can retrieve this map? Currently i am retriving this into jsp and then passing it to JQuery...

Comment: You would need to output javascript variable in jsp or in some div. the jquery can then use that variable or lookup the div.